# What will be the effect of density on relaxation time?

Tags: simulations, density, polymers

I am doing a Monte Carlo simulation of protein chains of various lengths.

I change the densities of the simulation box.

In my experiment, I found that density has no effect on relaxation time.

Do you think this is plausible?

If not, what mistake should I look for?

Comment: "Monte-Carlo simulation" really can mean anything that uses random numbers. Can you give some more detail on how in terms of physical models and computational algorithms you are simulating?

Comment: @Zaph, I am experimenting with a novel coarse-grained (CG) model of protein chains. The computational algorithm is plain old MCMC with some additional techniques for increasing randomness. This is my source paper.https://cmst.eu/wp-content/uploads/files/10.12921_cmst.2016.0000052_Sikorski.pdf.

Comment: Well, how does time enter into your simulation?

Comment: @JonCuster, In my simulation, `time` simply means the MCMC steps. Relaxation time means the autocorrelation time for a protein chain.

Comment: So the number of random interactions to get to some state is the same for two different densities? Which is what I would suspect. For different densities, the average time between interactions changes, not the number of interactions to do something.

Comment: @JonCuster, *So the number of random interactions to get to some state is the same for two different densities?* --- I am not clear what you meant here.

Comment: The amount of the steps you need for equilibration, will very much depend on the exact way of how you construct the steps in your Markov chain and how you choose your starting configuration. Since we don’t know how you are doing that, it does not seem to me, that we could give you any answer concerning, what to expect for your needed equilibration time. I understand it right, that when talking about relaxation time you refer to the time at the start of your simulation, in which you do not take measurements, to remove correlation from your artificial start point?

Comment: @JonCuster I also do not understand, what you are saying in your comment. From my understanding user366312 is not trying to simulate any real time dynamics. He just generates a Markov chain of states, which should reproduce the statistical right result in terms of the distribution of states, when looking at a large enough chain. The neighboring states in the chain do not have to be connected in any physical meaningful way.

Comment: @Zaph, *I understand it right, that when talking about relaxation time, you refer to the time at the start of your simulation, in which you do not take measurements, to remove correlation from your artificial start point?* --- I ran the simulation long enough, visually inspected the convergence, then truncated 50% of the rows from the front of the dataset. Then I computed autocorrelation, and so forth.

Comment: And you are irritated that the auto correlation you get after that procedure does not show a significant density dependence? Is that the core your problem?

Comment: @Zaph, I am not `irritated`. I am just curious. Coz, my professor says that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Ok, I still think it will be hard for anyone to give you interesting answers without knowing how exactly our Markov steps are generated, but, if you want to get more people then just me to think about it, I suggest you edit your question by including some of the information you gave my threw the comments in it. Right now I think it’s kind of hard to understand what exactly your asking about from the question alone.

Comment: How do you define time in your simulation? What determines it?

Comment: @JonCuster, I already wrote. In my MCMC simulation, `time` means simulation steps. If the simulation runs for 1000 iterations, there are 1000 steps. I.e., it ran for 1000 units of time. This is not clock time or watch time.

Comment: @JonCuster, The number of steps is supplied by the user as a command line argument of the simulation program.

Comment: Say you are doing gas molecule interactions with MC. Nothing happens until a collision between two gas molecules. The real time (wall clock) time between such collisions varies with density. Simulating $n$ MC interactions or collisions yields the same result regardless of density.

Comment: @JonCuster, https://imgur.com/UahYzFt

Comment: @JonCuster, Check my output plot. Plz, write an explanatory answer.